# Updating extensions after PHP upgrade on CentOS 5.6

Tags: linux, centos, upgrade, plesk, php5

I'm completely new to pecl, yum, rpm, packages and all the stuff required to get this done, so I'm hoping some of you smarter more experienced people can help me out. I only have a vague notion of what I'm doing.

I upgraded PHP 5.3.3-26.el5_11 to 5.4.45-3.el5.remi based on this article: https://kb.odin.com/en/115833

After upgrading, I'm getting PHP warnings:

```
    Unable to initialize module
    Module compiled with module API=20090626
    PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
    Unable to load dynamic library
    undefined symbol: php_checkuid in Unknown on line 0
```

The solutions described in [another thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/154715/unable-to-initialize-module-warning-after-update-php-on-centos-5-4) are to reinstall or update the extensions.

Searching around, I have tried commands like:

```
    $pecl install ldap
    No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/ldap”
    install failed

    $ pecl upgrade ldap
    No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/ldap"
    install failed

    $ yum update php-mcrypt
    Package(s) php-mcrypt available, but not installed.
    No Packages marked for Update
```

I'm at a loss here, and I don't want to keep running commands as root when I don't know what I'm doing, or even what directory I'm supposed to be in. Can someone provide detail on how to do this please?

Here are the full warnings I'm getting:

```
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ldap: Unable to initialize module
    Module compiled with module API=20090626
    PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
    These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mcrypt: Unable to initialize module
    Module compiled with module API=20090626
    PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
    These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/odbc.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/odbc.so:
    undefined symbol: php_checkuid in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: PDO_ODBC: Unable to initialize module
    Module compiled with module API=20090626
    PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
    These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: snmp: Unable to initialize module
    Module compiled with module API=20090626
    PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
    These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: xmlrpc: Unable to initialize module
    Module compiled with module API=20090626
    PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
    These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Well, the first issue I see is you are running `CentOS 5.6`, and not at least `5.11`. The second issue is there is obvious breakage somewhere. I highly recommend getting a full `yum update` out of the way before troubleshooting any further.

Comment: By "full yum update", do you mean updating the OS? I'm not able to do that on this server. Why is 5.6 an issue?

Comment: You are completely prone to many security vulnerabilities. If this machine is front facing, your chance of getting pwned is ridiculously high, especially since you are using PHP. You cannot give the excuse of "I'm not able to do that". It doesn't matter if it's yours, a customers, or a server inside of your company's network. The reason why I'm saying you need to do a full update is because it will rule out whether or not if there were patches released to fix this issue.

Comment: "I'm not able to do that" isn't an excuse. The hosting company does not allow it on the service I'm using. I'm look for more specific direction as opposed to general commentaries.

Comment: You'll need to find a CentOS 5.6 version of the packages. Also make sure you've completely removed every trace of the old packages first. `pecl` is probably configured with the old-php path.

Comment: Thank you @Will. I tried to remove those extensions using "pecl uninstall", but the output i got was "pecl/module not installed". I'm not sure if this is what you mean by removing old packages. Can you give me some specifics of where pecl configuration may be? Sorry, I'm brand new and although I can make my way around the file system and make file edits,  I'm not experienced with packages and how to install, compile, or use pecl or pear. I'm really at a loss.

Comment: Have you tried completely removing PHP and then installing [this way](https://webtatic.com/packages/php54/)?

Comment: Yes, as far I understand, I followed the instruction in the Odin article https://kb.odin.com/en/115833 which completely removes PHP 5.3 components and configurator.

Comment: You should probably remove the `centos` tag from this article, since it's not really CentOS anymore, but some fork made by your hosting company that doesn't use CentOS packages anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is:

```
yum install php-module
```

So if for example, I needed to update ldap, the command would be:

```
yum install php-ldap
```

This resolved all the warnings.

Refer to http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/ for more detailed instruction.